# Inserting contents of array into object not working

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm creating an invoice object that takes a product line parameter. Because an order can have many products, I'm using an iterator that collects an array of line items. $prod_line is an array that holds the collection of product line arrays.

I was hoping I would be able to inject the contents of $prod_line into my object, but I only have success when using $prod_line[0] or $prod_line[1].

I have tried a few techniques to remove the parent layer array, such as array_merge_recursive -- but I've been stuck on this silly issue for a few hours with no luck and really need to progress.

Help would be much appreciated!!

NOTE: code below is stripped down for readability -- ignore missing variable instantiation and use for concept.

### Quickbooks_Invoice.php

```
 function create_qb_invoice()
     {

           foreach ($az as $order_id => $order) // FOR EACH ORDER
           {
             $line_id = 1;

             foreach ($order['products'] as $product) // FOR EACH PRODUCTS
             {

               // A 'LINE' STANDS FOR AN ITEMIZED PRODUCT LINE IN QUICKBOOKS INVOICE FORMS

                  // FOR EACH PRODUCT, CREATE A LINE FOR QUICKBOOKS INVOICE
                  $prod_line[] =
                  [
                     "Id" => $line_id,
                     "LineNum" => $line_id,
                     "Amount" => $product['ItemPrice']['Amount'],
                     "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
                     "SalesItemLineDetail" => [
                         "ItemRef" => [
                         "value" => $theItemId,
                         "name" => $theItemName
                         ],
                         "TaxCodeRef" => [
                         "value" => "NON"
                         ],
                         "UnitPrice" =>  $product['ItemPrice']['Amount'],
                         "Qty" => $product['QuantityOrdered'],
                       ]
                     ];

                    $line_id ++;

                }

                $myInvoiceObj = Invoice::create([
                  "LinkedTxn" => [],
                  "Line" =>
                  [
                      // THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED WITH THE $prod_line VARIABLE
                      // HOWEVER I'VE ONLY BEEN ABLE TO USE $prod_line[0], OR $prod_line[1]
                      // REGULAR $prod_line HAS AN EXTRA LAYER OF ARRAY THAT Invoice::create WON'T BE EXPECTING
                      // STRIPPING AWAY THE CONTAINING ARRAY IS NOT WORKING WHEN i USE array_merge_recursive or similar solutions

                      // [
                      //     "Id" => "1",
                      //     "LineNum" => 1,
                      //     "Amount" => $order['ItemPrice']['Amount'],
                      //     "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
                      //     "SalesItemLineDetail" =>
                      //     [
                      //         "ItemRef" =>
                      //         [
                      //             "value" => $theItemId,
                      //             "name" => $theItemName
                      //         ],
                      //         "TaxCodeRef" =>
                      //         [
                      //             "value" => "NON"
                      //         ]
                      //     ]
                      //   ],
                        [
                            "Amount" => $order['OrderTotal']['Amount'],
                            "DetailType" => "SubTotalLineDetail",
                            "SubTotalLineDetail" => []
                        ]
                    ],
                    "CustomerRef" =>
                    [
                        "value" => "18269",
                        "name" => "Amazon"
                    ]
                  ]);

                   $resultingInvoiceObj = $dataService->Add($myInvoiceObj);

           }//for

     }
```

### var dump of $prod_line

```
array(2) { // this array layer should be stripped out
  [0]=>
  array(5) { // and this array-- just want to pass the inner contents
    ["Id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["LineNum"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Amount"]=>
    string(6) "366.97"
    ["DetailType"]=>
    string(19) "SalesItemLineDetail"
    ["SalesItemLineDetail"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["ItemRef"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(4) "9378"
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "Countryman E6OW5C2SR"
      }
      ["TaxCodeRef"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "NON"
      }
      ["UnitPrice"]=>
      strin

g(6) "366.97"
          ["Qty"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["LineNum"]=>
        int(2)
        ["Amount"]=>
        string(6) "365.81"
        ["DetailType"]=>
        string(19) "SalesItemLineDetail"
        ["SalesItemLineDetail"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["ItemRef"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["value"]=>
            string(4) "9392"
            ["name"]=>
            string(20) "Countryman E6OW5T2SR"
          }
          ["TaxCodeRef"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["value"]=>
            string(3) "NON"
          }
          ["UnitPrice"]=>
          string(6) "365.81"
          ["Qty"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing why you're creating the `$prod_line` array at all.  If you do really need it somewhere that you're not showing though, then just assign all the "line" stuff to an array, push _that_ onto `$prod_line` and then also assign it to the "Line" index in your invoice array

Comment: I also notice that you don't clear $prod_line after each loop.  That means each invoice will contain the products of the previous invoice.

Comment: This is a stripped down example so it's easy to see the issue. Therefore, don't worry about clearing variables and such -- This file is actually very large and has more code than shown.

Comment: I do need $product_line. This variable is collecting item iterations (while inside the product foreach) -- and then filling only part of the line object -- amount, detailtype, ect should not go through iterations.

Comment: If you have better suggestions please provide pseudo code - thanks

Comment: @ThisBetterWork have a ponder at my answers code then comment if it dont work.

Comment: I'm on it! Thanks Lawrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you populate `$prod_line` items do an additional `$prod_line[]` to add the `Amount`, array. Its not because its an array that it strips it it's because its not the correct structure.

Your essentially doing:

```
<?php
$prod_line = [
    ['key' => 'value'],
    ['key' => 'value']
];

$final = [
    $prod_line,
    [
        'key' => 'value'
    ]    
];
```

Which will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => value
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => value
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
        )

)
```

Which is not the correct structure.

Instead you should be building your final array as you go along.

```
<?php
function create_qb_invoice()
{
    foreach ($az as $order_id => $order) // FOR EACH ORDER
    {
        $prod_line = [];
        $line_id = 1;

        foreach ($order['products'] as $product) // FOR EACH PRODUCTS
        {
            $prod_line[] =
                [
                "Id" => $line_id,
                "LineNum" => $line_id,
                "Amount" => $product['ItemPrice']['Amount'],
                "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
                "SalesItemLineDetail" => [
                    "ItemRef" => [
                        "value" => $theItemId,
                        "name" => $theItemName
                    ],
                    "TaxCodeRef" => [
                        "value" => "NON"
                    ],
                    "UnitPrice" =>  $product['ItemPrice']['Amount'],
                    "Qty" => $product['QuantityOrdered'],
                ]
            ];
            $line_id++;
        }

        $prod_line[] = [
            "Amount" => $order['OrderTotal']['Amount'],
            "DetailType" => "SubTotalLineDetail",
            "SubTotalLineDetail" => []
        ]

        $myInvoiceObj = Invoice::create([
            "LinkedTxn" => [],
            "Line" => $prod_line,
            "CustomerRef" =>
            [
                "value" => "18269",
                "name" => "Amazon"
            ]
        ]);

        $resultingInvoiceObj = $dataService->Add($myInvoiceObj);

    }//for

}
```

The correct array structure of this call can be found [here](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK) (halfway down):

```
$myInvoiceObj = Invoice::create([
  "DocNumber" => "1070",
  "LinkedTxn" => [],
  "Line" => [[
      "Id" => "1",
      "LineNum" => 1,
      "Amount" => 150.0,
      "DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail",
      "SalesItemLineDetail" => [
          "ItemRef" => [
              "value" => "1",
              "name" => "Services"
          ],
          "TaxCodeRef" => [
              "value" => "NON"
          ]
      ]
  ], [
      "Amount" => 150.0,
      "DetailType" => "SubTotalLineDetail",
      "SubTotalLineDetail" => []
  ]],
  "CustomerRef" => [
      "value" => "1",
      "name" => "Amy's Bird Sanctuary"
  ]
]);
$resultingInvoiceObj = $dataService->Add($myInvoiceObj);
```

Comment: I had tried something similar and wound up moving away from it only because there was some awkwardness when adding the extra amount, detail type, ect.

But this direction does look like a better option. I will try this out - thanks!!

Comment: I think the issue is simply because you have an array and then your trying to place/merge that array with the final structure array which, wont work, your need to merge or populate it before.

Comment: This worked :) :) -- I guess I got stuck on doing it the other way (which was a mess).

Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.